# RaisePropertyChanged Triggering "set" On Different Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I was working on a project when I came across an issue with RaisePropertyChanged from MVVM Light that I can't seem to figure out. When I try to raise a change for my list, the list does get updated, but as does the selected index value above. The value that is passed to my selected index appears to be influenced by what key was pressed to trigger the event (i.e. if I press "BACKSPACE", the value passed to the setter is "-1", whereas if I enter a letter, the value passed is "0")

I recreated a project which purely demonstrates the issue. Below is the main bit of logic found in the MainVeiwModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _testItems = new List<TestItem>()
        {
            new TestItem() { Name = "Test1" },
            new TestItem() { Name = "Test2" }
        };
    }

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedText");
            RaisePropertyChanged("TestList");
        }
    }

    public string SelectedText
    {
        get
        {
            return _testItems[_selectedIndex].Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _testItems[_selectedIndex].Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TextList");
        }
    }

    public List<string> TextList
    {
        get
        {
            _textList = new List<string>();
            if (_testItems != null && _testItems.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (TestItem item in _testItems)
                    _textList.Add(item.Name);
            }
            return _textList;
        }
        set { _textList = value; }
    }

    private int _selectedIndex;
    private List<string> _textList;
    private List<TestItem> _testItems;
}
```

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="RaisePropertyBug.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RaisePropertyBug"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TextList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

For context: I have a ComboBox which lists the names from a collection of items I have. There is an edit window where users can change names and other properties of these items. My goal is to have the ComboBox list update as the user edits the value. In my actual program, you are able to do this with the item at index 0, but any other index will automatically change to 0 as soon as a key is pressed and the RaisePropertyChanged() area is reached.

Comment: Could you share xaml part as well?

Comment: You don't need RaisePropertyChanged("TestList") or UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the binding for ItemsSource - the list never changes value.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the actual program, the list can also be added and removed from in the user interface. But that functionality worked as expected, so I didn't have it included here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code if it's working as per your requirement.

Use `SelectedItem` property of `ComboBox` and bind selecteditem to the edit screen/textbox. I've bind `SelectedTestItem.Name` propety here.

View -

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTestItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedTestItem.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

View.cs -

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TestItem selectedTestItem;

    public TestItem SelectedTestItem
    {
        get { return selectedTestItem; }
        set
        {
            selectedTestItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTestItem");
        }
    }



    public List<TestItem> TestItems
    {
        get;
        set;

    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        var items = new List<TestItem>()
                {
                    new TestItem() { Name = "Test1" },
                    new TestItem() { Name = "Test2" }
                };

        TestItems = items;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. DisplayMemberPath was what I needed. Hadn't thought about using that, and instead made everything far too convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need INotifyPropertyChanged for this example. I'm not entirely certain of what you are trying to achieve, but this code will achieve what I have gleaned from your post.

```
<Window x:Class="RaisePropertyChangedExample.BindingExample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Correct View" Width="150" Height="80">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                x:Name="ItemViews"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
      <TextBox DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ItemViews}" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and the supporting code

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace RaisePropertyChangedExample
{
   public partial class BindingExample : Window
   {
      public BindingExample()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = new BindingExampleViewModel();
      }
   }

   public class BindingExampleViewModel
   {
      public ObservableCollection<TestItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
         = new ObservableCollection<TestItemViewModel>(new List<TestItemViewModel>
         {
            new TestItemViewModel {Name = "Test1"},
            new TestItemViewModel {Name = "Test2"}
         });
   }

   public class TestItemViewModel
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Unless there is some need of the `index` of the selected `Item`, there is no real argument against simply exposing each item as a `TestItemViewModel` view model and binding the other controls directly to the selected item itself. If however other controls are bound to the members of the `TestItemViewModel` then it's still not necessarily true that you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged on that view model.

The following example will still display the correct information when wired up with the existing ViewModel:

```
<Window x:Class="RaisePropertyChangedExample.BindingExample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Correct View" Width="150" Height="100">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                x:Name="Combo"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
      <Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Combo}">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
         <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Content="{Binding Name}" />
      </Grid>
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Normally

> *Updating after every keystroke can diminish performance and it denies the user the usual opportunity to backspace and fix typing errors before committing to the new value*. [see MS reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2)

however, this is only an issue if other processing occurs as the result of updating the source. If you are worried about the amount of processing involved you can switch to the default behaviour of `LostFocus` by simply omitting `UpdateSourceTrigger' declaration.